# Scraping data using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape some data from my uni website using request and beautifulsoup4.
I am trying to scrape this data but I am confused with all of the elements here. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="_27_1termCourses__8_1" style="">
    <h4 class="u_indent" id="anonymous_element_13">Courses where you are: Student</h4> 
    <ul class="portletList-img courseListing coursefakeclass u_indent">
        <li>
            <img alt="" src="/images/ci/icons/bookopen_li.gif" width="12" height="12">
            <a href=" /launcher?type=Course&amp;id=_65254_1&amp;url=" target="_top">1430101_10777_FALL2017-2018: Astro &amp; Space Sciences </a>
                <div class="courseInformation">
                    <span class="courseRole">
                    Instructor:
                    </span>
                    <span class="name">here is the name that i want to get it;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="" src="/images/ci/icons/bookopen_li.gif" width="12" height="12">
            <a href=" /launcher?type=Course&amp;id=_65816_1&amp;url=" target="_top">0403201_12360_FALL2017-2018: Digital Logic Design </a>
                <div class="courseInformation">
                    <span class="courseRole">
                    Instructor:
                    </span>
                    <span class="name">here is the name that i want to get it ;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0','Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

url = 'https://url/'
url_ajax = "url/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction"

#data
payload = {'user_id': '','password': ''}
course_data = {'action' : 'refreshAjaxModule','modId' : '_27_1','tabId' : '_1_1' ,'tab_tab_group_id' : '_1_1'}

#post data
session = requests.Session()
session.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload) #username and password
UrlAjx= session.post(url_ajax , headers=headers, data= course_data) #get the ajax call

#get the html elements
soup = BeautifulSoup(UrlAjx.text, 'lxml')
r1 = soup.find_all('div',  attrs={ 'id':'re.compile(" [_27_1termCourses]__\d+" )' } )
result = []
// i tried a lot of codes here before i post this question but nothings works 
for res in r1 :
    ul = res.find('ul',attrs={'class':'portletList-img courseListing coursefakeclass u_indent'})
    
    result.append((li_element))
print(result)
```

Comment: The problem is with regex, not with requests or BeautifulSoup; more specifically the `'re.compile(" [_27_1termCourses]__\d+" )'` part. Firstly, it's enclosed in quotes, which should not be. Secondly `[...]` is used for matching any one of the characters present within those brackets.

Comment: Suggestion with BeautifulSoup: If the `div` tags you're filtering into `r1` contain only one `ul` tag, it's pointless to find the `ul` in your for loop, let alone use `attrs={'class':'portletList-img courseListing coursefakeclass u_indent'}` argument. You can simply use `res.ul`, or remove the intermediary `ul` altogether and use `result.extend(res.findAll('li'))`.

Comment: @Mahesh actually the regex is working fine with the next code  print([element.get_text(strip=True) for element in soup.find_all(id=r1)]) and i tried your solution result.extend(res.findAll('li')) but all what i got is nothing but []

Comment: Right after you assign to `r1`, print it and post the output.

Comment: [_27_1termCourses]__\d+
does NOT capture any underscores ("_") in the course name at the end of the name, as "[\d]" only captures "[0-9]". I believe a correct regular expression would be:
_27_1termCourses[\d_]+